# $orderby event start time in MS graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm currently running this query successfully in graph explorer:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/07805...9e84/events`

However, I want to sort and filter (I'll save the latter for another question).

The link above returns an object which contains the following:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-08-19T15:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
},
```

I've tried the following, with the accompanying results:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0780...9e84/events?$orderby=start desc`

> "The $orderby expression must evaluate to a single value of primitive type.",

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0780...9e84/events?$orderby=start.dateTime desc`

> The child type 'start.dateTime' in a cast was not an entity type. Casts can only be performed on entity types.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exception you have pasted, I have understood that the orderby parameter is taking two values(i.e start and desc) but it needs only one value. From the intellisence in Graph Explorer we can understand that `$orderby=start desc` is correct. So here I tried to encode the URL as below and ran it. It worked.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?%24orderby%3Dstart desc`

[image]

There may be some kind of issue in Graph explorer that could be causing this issue or it may be at the server.

This should work for your group events API call as well.

Comment: This works: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0780...9e84/events?&orderby%3Dstart desc` and this does not: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0780...9e84/events?&orderby=start desc`. So it seems to be the `=` character that breaks it.